# Save_post acf data not updating category of post type

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, save-post

i am trying to assign multiple categories to my Custom Post Type using advanced custom field named 'cat'. But there is nothing saving to my categories.
Any help?

```
<?php
// Add an action to run on post save
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_genre_on_save' );
function set_genre_on_save( $post_id ){
    // Check the post type
    if (is_single('hvm')) {
        // Get the custom field data
        $custom_field_data = get_post_custom( $post_id );
        // Check if there is any category entered in the metabox
        if (isset($custom_box_data['cat'])) {
            // Save the data (separated by comma) into an array
            $genre_array = explode( ',', $custom_box_data['cat'] );
            //Set the array values to lower case
            foreach ($genre_array as $genre){
                $genre = strtolower($genre);
            }
            // Set the categories for these genres
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $genre_array, 'category' );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use [is_single()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) conditional tag here.

You can check the type of post in the function this way:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_genre_on_save', 20, 3 );
function set_genre_on_save( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ($post->post_type != 'hvm')
        return;

    // ...
}
```

You can also attach the function to the action hook [save_post_{post_type}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/), which is triggered only for the `{post_type}` type. Then there is no need to check the type of post inside the function.

```
add_action( 'save_post_hvm', 'set_genre_on_save', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: Still does nothing, any idea how it comes?

Comment: @Dennis Are you sure that `$custom_box_data['cat']` is a string, not an array? It seems to me that `get_post_custom()` returns every meta field as an array.

Comment: what should i use instead, im kinda stuck on this..

Comment: @Dennis If you have one `cat` custom field per post, try using [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) `custom_field_data = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'cat', true);`.

Comment: I have multiple fields, one field is 'cat' per cpt. The above solution still dont write the categories.

Comment: I found the code from this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269815/assign-category-using-custom-field

It also seemed as the correct anwser but is doing nothing for me

Comment: @Dennis What is the type of `cat` field? A text field or another?  Can you check what value has a  `$custom_box_data['cat']`? Use `var_dump` or `print_r`.

Comment: The type is just a text field, how can i see these values in wordpress because i aint seeing anything with those

Comment: After `get_post_custom()` or `get_post_meta()`  add `var_dump( $custom_field_data ); exit;`. If you're using a classic editor, you'll see the result on the screen, if you're using the Gutenberg editor, open the developer tools in your browser (often the F12 key), go to the "Network" tab, check the result of saving changes to the post in this tab.

Comment: Well, im adding this code in my functions.php file how can i see this result then?

Comment: In the browser, when updating post. If you use WordPress 5.0 or newer, you may need development tools for this ([FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor), [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/)).

Comment: I found it out with combining 2 pieces of code i found about this topic :). It only works if you type the slug of the category though.